# SDN 4 and Cypher redundant parentheses

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my SDN 4 project in order to implement required functionality I implemented my own Cypher Query builder.

Right now I'm worried about redundant parentheses in the builder output, for example:

```
( id(characteristic) = 138 AND  (  (rdc.value > 5000.32)) AND (  (rdc.value < 50000.32)) )
```

Can it potentially affect performance of my application or I can not worry about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think the redundant parentheses are a problem, but with or without them, always good to profile your queries. With only the conditions specified above, it's hard to say overall what the query does and how it performs